# as there anyway to enable user to zoom text in UIWebView in iphone applicaiton

Tags: iphone

I am display text in UIWebview as there any way to enable user to zoom the text when they are reading the text.I have set font to 4 in html string.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set UiWebview scalesPageToFit property to YES

```
objWebview.scalesPageToFit = YES; // objWebview - object of UiWebview
```